# How to access two file from two NameNodes from a job

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In Hadoop 2, there can be more then one NameNode actively working, so if there is an application which requires access to two files, one under one NameNode and another under a second NameNode, then how will the application be able to access those two files? Or what will be the workflow to access those files by one application?
Any link will also be preferable.

Comment: Please, try to make your question more readable. I cannot understand much as it is now.

Comment: There is only one namenode in a cluster and the secondary namenode is just a redundant namenode in case of failure

Comment: @AntarikshaYelkawar , in yarn federation there can be any number of namenode